# avoid duplicate in mysql insert

Tags: mysql

I have a friends table that has 'id', 'friend (INTEGER)' and 'user (INTEGER)' fields.

A friend relationship exists between user and friend.
i.e.

```
id     user     friend

6       22        45

7       45        22
```

is the same friend relationship and should be considered a duplicate record.

I want to input a whole lot of records at once, so something like:

```
INSERT INTO friends (user, friend) VALUES(22, 34), (22, 76), (22, 567)...;
```

In this situation, I can easily use IGNORE to avoid entering a duplicate (22, 34) entry(if (22, 34) already exists), but is there a way I can also avoid entering (22, 34) if (34, 22) already exists, as this is the same relationship.

Comment: Easiest way: Always sort your relation pair(s) before inserting: `(22,45) -> (22,45); (45,22) -> (22,45);` and keep a unique key constraint across both columns.

Comment: @satishrajak you didn't read the question, did you?

Comment: You can add a before insert trigger to check the friends column for the key and abort the insert if the relation already exists. However the way you want to set up this code I can call you my friend, and you might not agree. So your second insert (45,22) is more the confirmation of this friendship, which you just seem to want to skip.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Norbert. Indeed, this insert only happens when an invited friend "approves" the invitation. I really don't want there to be duplicates in this table as this would complicate other lookup code (I would have to handle duplicates).
I may end up going with @dognose suggestion as it seem easiest to implement, however, I'm curious about your trigger. Can this be implemented in the same query as the insert? I don't want to hit the DB multiple times if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort each pair; then do `INSERT IGNORE` to avoid error messages.

You can sort as you insert by doing

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (LEAST($a, $b), GREATEST($a, $b));
```

However, in order to do a batch insert, you should probably sort in the client language.

Another issue:  `INSERT IGNORE` will create an `id` before it checks for dup.  Therefore, lots of `AUTO_INCREMENT` values will be 'burned'.

Rather than explaining how to avoid the burning, I will say that there seems to be no good reason for `id`.  Instead have

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, friend_id)
```

Another issue with the sorting...  `SELECT` may need to do a `UNION`:

```
( SELECT ... WHERE user_id = $x )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... WHERE friend_id = $x )
```

That implies that you need this, too:

```
INDEX(friend_id, user_id)
```